# CanvasJS pie chart display 0% instead of NaN%

Tags: nan, canvasjs

How can I display for percentages in the pie chart of Canvasjs to be 0% and not NaN%. thank you. please answer

Comment: instead of downing the lastest version

Answer (score 0):

Please [download the latest version](http://canvasjs.com/download-html5-charting-graphing-library/) in which the bug has been fixed.